Stripe webhook handling error in Next.js app. Webhook Error: No signatures found matching the expected signature for payload
I'm trying to handle Stripe webhook events though my api handlers in Next.js. Seems like I'm not passing the raw request body to stripe for the event creation, as I'm receiving the following error:

Error message: No signatures found matching the expected signature for payload. Are you passing the raw request body you received from Stripe?
Learn more about webhook signing and explore webhook integration examples for various frameworks at https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node#webhook-signing

Stripe apiVersion: '2024-04-10'
I've tried everything: app/api routing (couldn't make it work as I'm running it on Vercel and I cannot implement the config block). Now I have it implemented in the src/pages/api routing approach. I've used the raw-body library, I've implemented a manual buffer parser as in the Stripe examples: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node/blob/master/examples/webhook-signing/nextjs/pages/api/webhooks.ts
I've been stuck for 3 days on this. This is my current implementation, please do share any information if you have it:
import Stripe from 'stripe';
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';
import { stripe } from '@/lib/stripe';
import { db } from '@/db';
import getRawBody from 'raw-body';

const endpointSecret = process.env.STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET!;

export const config = {
  api: {
    bodyParser: false, // This is correct, ensure this is in place
  },
};

const handler = async (
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse
): Promise<void> => {
  if (req.method === 'POST') {
    let event;
    let rawBody;

    try {
      rawBody = await getRawBody(req);
    } catch (err: any) {
      console.error('Error getting raw body:', err.message);
      res.status(400).send(`Error getting raw body: ${err.message}`);
      return;
    }

    const sig = req.headers['stripe-signature'] as string;

    console.log('Raw Body:', rawBody.toString()); // Log the raw body
    console.log('Signature:', sig); // Log the signature

    try {
      event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(rawBody, sig, endpointSecret);
      console.log('Event:', event); // Log the event to ensure it is constructed properly
    } catch (err: any) {
      console.log(`Error message: ${err.message}`);
      res.status(400).send(`Webhook Error: ${err.message}`);
      return;
    }

    const session = event.data.object as Stripe.Checkout.Session;

    if (!session?.metadata?.userId) {
      console.log('Im in the stripe webhook 4');
      res.status(200).send("OK");
      return;
    }

    try {
      if (event.type === 'checkout.session.completed') {
        const subscription = await stripe.subscriptions.retrieve(
          session.subscription as string
        );

        await db.user.update({
          where: {
            id: session.metadata.userId,
          },
          data: {
            stripeSubscriptionId: subscription.id,
            stripeCustomerId: subscription.customer as string,
            stripePriceId: subscription.items.data[0]?.price.id,
            stripeCurrentPeriodEnd: new Date(
              subscription.current_period_end * 1000
            ),
          },
        });
      }

      if (event.type === 'invoice.payment_succeeded') {
        const subscription = await stripe.subscriptions.retrieve(
          session.subscription as string
        );

        await db.user.update({
          where: {
            stripeSubscriptionId: subscription.id,
          },
          data: {
            stripePriceId: subscription.items.data[0]?.price.id,
            stripeCurrentPeriodEnd: new Date(
              subscription.current_period_end * 1000
            ),
          },
        });
      }

      if (event.type === 'payment_intent.succeeded') {
        const subscription = await stripe.subscriptions.retrieve(
          session.subscription as string
        );

        await db.user.update({
          where: {
            stripeSubscriptionId: subscription.id,
          },
          data: {
            stripePriceId: subscription.items.data[0]?.price.id,
            stripeCurrentPeriodEnd: new Date(
              subscription.current_period_end * 1000
            ),
          },
        });
      }

      console.log('Event processed successfully.');
      res.json({ received: true });
    } catch (err: any) {
      console.log(`Error message: ${err.message}`);
      res.status(400).send(`Webhook Error: ${err.message}`);
      return;
    }
  } else {
    res.setHeader('Allow', 'POST');
    res.status(405).end('Method Not Allowed');
  }
};

export default handler;

What have I tried?
Stripe example: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node/blob/master/examples/webhook-signing/nextjs/pages/api/webhooks.ts
Manual raw body parsing:
const readStreamToBuffer = async (stream: ReadableStream<Uint8Array> | null): Promise<Buffer> => {
  if (!stream) {
    throw new Error('Stream is null');
  }

  const reader = stream.getReader();
  const chunks: Uint8Array[] = [];

  while (true) {
    const { done, value } = await reader.read();
    if (done) break;
    if (value) chunks.push(value);
  }

  return Buffer.concat(chunks);
};

Routing approaches: src/app/api & src/pages/api

This is a common issue when you have a framework that tried to be helpful and changed the body. When you calculate the signature the string wasn't exactly the same as what Stripe sent.
I would be skeptical about the getRawBody method, and try the exact code as the example:
const body = await buffer(req);


I've tried it and I still receive the same error
